# React Context API getting their default data when changing routes in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

**_app.tsx:**

```
'use client';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import  NavBar  from '@/Components/NavBar/NavBar';
import { NextUIProvider } from '@nextui-org/react'
import BlogState from '@/Context/blogState';
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
 
  return<BlogState> 
    <NextUIProvider>
  <div style={{
    display:"flex",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent:"center",
    fontSize:"50px",
    marginBottom:"30px"
  }}>Blog</div>
   <NavBar/>
   <Component {...pageProps} />
   </NextUIProvider>
   </BlogState>
}
```

**blogState.tsx:**

```
import BlogContext from "./blogContext";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const BlogState:any=(props:any)=>{
    
    const [Login,SetLogin]=useState(false)
    const [userDetail,setUserDetail]=useState({})

    function setLogin(val:boolean){
        SetLogin(()=>val)
    }
    function setUserDetails(val:any){
        setUserDetail((prev)=>prev=val)
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
      console.log(Login)
      console.log(userDetail)
    },[Login,userDetail])

    return (
        <BlogContext.Provider value={{setUserDetails,setLogin,Login,userDetail}}>
            {props.children}
        </BlogContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default BlogState
```

**Login**

```
 const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
  const [message,setMessage]=useState("")
  const {setUserDetails,setLogin}=useContext(blogContext)
  const[loading,setLoding]=useState(false)
  const[email,setEmail]=useState("")
  const[password,setPassword]=useState("")
  function LoginUser(){
    if(email==""||email==undefined||password==""||password==undefined){
      setMessage(()=>"Please fill all feilds")
      setVisible(()=>true)
      return;
    }
    setLoding(()=>true)
    axios.post("/api/Users/Login",
      {
        email:email,
        password:password
      }
    ).then((res:any)=>{
      if(res.data.details=="No User Found"){
        setMessage(()=>"Email is not connected with any account")
        setVisible(()=>true)
        setLoding(()=>false)
         return;
      }
      if(res.data.details=="Password Incorrect"){
        setMessage(()=>"Email or password incorrect")
        setVisible(()=>true)
        setLoding(()=>false)
         return;
      }
      setLoding(()=>false)
      setLogin(true)
      setUserDetails(res.data)
    }).catch(e=>console.log(e))
  }
```

**HomePage:**

```
export default function Home() {
  const{Login}=useContext(blogContext)
  console.log(Login)
  return <div style={{display:"flex",alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"center",flexDirection:"column"}}>
    <Quote title1='Conversation is king.' title2='Content is just something to talk about.'/>
   <div className={classes.blogs}>
      <CardB/>
    <CardB/>
    <CardB/>
    <CardB/>
    <CardB/>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

**NavBAr**

```
import { Navbar, Link, Text, Avatar, Dropdown, Input } from "@nextui-org/react";
import { Layout } from "./Layout";
export default function App() {
  const collapseItems = [
    "Home",
    "Create",
    "Favourite",
    "About",
  ];

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Navbar isBordered variant="sticky">
        <Navbar.Toggle showIn="xs" />
        <Text b>Bloging Made Easy</Text>
        <Navbar.Content
          enableCursorHighlight
          activeColor="secondary"
          hideIn="xs"
          variant="highlight-rounded"
        >
          <Navbar.Link href="/">Home</Navbar.Link>
          <Navbar.Link href="/Create">Create</Navbar.Link>
          <Navbar.Link href="/Favourite">Favourite</Navbar.Link>
          <Navbar.Link href="#">About</Navbar.Link>
        </Navbar.Content>
        <Navbar.Content
          css={{
            "@xs": {
              w: "12%",
              jc: "flex-end",
            },
          }}
        >
          <Dropdown placement="bottom-right">
            <Navbar.Item>
              <Dropdown.Trigger>
                <Avatar
                  bordered
                  as="button"
                  color="secondary"
                  size="md"
                  src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1208175274/vector/avatar-vector-icon-simple-element-illustrationavatar-vector-icon-material-concept-vector.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=t4aK_TKnYaGQcPAC5Zyh46qqAtuoPcb-mjtQax3_9Xc="
                />
              </Dropdown.Trigger>
            </Navbar.Item>
            <Dropdown.Menu
              aria-label="User menu actions"
              color="secondary"
              onAction={(actionKey) => console.log({ actionKey })}
            >
              <Dropdown.Item key="profile" css={{ height: "$18" }}>
                <Text b color="inherit" css={{ d: "flex" }}>
                  Signed in as
                </Text>
                <Text b color="inherit" css={{ d: "flex" }}>
                  zoey@example.com
                </Text>
              </Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item key="settings" withDivider>
                <Link href="/Account">Account</Link>
              </Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item key="logout" withDivider color="error">
                Log Out
              </Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
          </Dropdown>
        </Navbar.Content>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          {collapseItems.map((item, index) => (
            <Navbar.CollapseItem
              key={item}
              activeColor="secondary"
              css={{
                color: index === collapseItems.length - 1 ? "$error" : "",
              }}
              isActive={index === 2}
            >
              <Link
                color="inherit"
                css={{
                  minWidth: "100%",
                }}
                href={(item=='Home')?"/":`/${item}`}
              >
                {item}
              </Link>
            </Navbar.CollapseItem>
          ))}
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

I tried to use the context API, but the values are getting to default value whenever I go to different component, although the whole app is wrapped within the context.

`useEffect` gets trigged and logs state of login and `userData` which works perfectly fine and update's the data but when it move to a different route the updated data is gone.

[Link to a video showing the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GMjIrP1kYHlbgXW2hVpNk72qLx3EQiIg/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you show where you have called `BlogState` component?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar I have edited the question and added the use of BlogState it is used in _app.tsx

Comment: Thanks. Now can you show the buttons in your `NavBar` component?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar Ya i have edited again and added the NavBar

Comment: Thanks. I have pasted an answer. Check it and let me know please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your video shows that the page is getting refreshed when you change routes (the reason why the context is getting reinitialized). I assume it's because that `Link` from `@nextui-org/react` is rendering a normal HMTL [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) element without any Next.js features. Use [`next/link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/link) instead:

```
import Link from "next/link";
```